# TeX's \write command sometimes induces a spurious vertical space

Tags: spacing, tex-core, write

in the process of debugging a problem with FiXme (reported by Lars Madsen), I fell on this issue which I'm afraid is beyond my expertise. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Theorem
  \begin{equation*}
    Equation
  \end{equation*}
  \makeatletter\write\@auxout{\string\relax}\makeatother % spurious vspace
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The call to `\write` produces a spurious vertical space in the document (comment this line or call a macro which does nothing to see the difference). I would like to understand what's going on, and whether this should be considered a bug somewhere or not (in the theorem environment?).

Thank you!

Comment: The spurious space vanishes if you use `\immediate\write` -- maybe the `whatsit` connected to `\write` causes this space

Comment: Yes. Without \immediate, \write puts a node in the (probably) vertical list here, which is probably why the spacing is affected. In the actual (non minimal) example, \write comes from a call to \addtocontents or \addcontentsline, and down the call stack, there's no \immediate.

Comment: Not surprising. The whatsit makes `\end{theorem}` to be scanned after a new partial paragraph (following the display) has started (better, the vertical list has something after the end of the display).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Display environments like proof/theorem etc, and section headings add space before and after the visible text using `\addvspace` this command tries to look whether a space has just been added to the vertical list and if so do not add the new space if the existing space is greater. This means that say two adjacent theorems do not get a double space between them form the end of one and the start of the other. (The action with a primitive display math is basically similar)

a whatsit from `\write` (or `\color` has similar problems) means that it is impossible to see the previous space and so the later environment always adds the full requested space at the start.

There is not much you can do about that other than do not add the whatsit there, for example if you added it after the P in Proof it would be OK.

The expl3 `xgalley` code addresses this but it is massively invasive it has to trap *every* command trying to add anything in vertical mode and make it delay its action and re-order things so that all spacing can be coalesced.