# Preserve vertical lastskip over \write

Tags: write, vskip

Is there a way to save a vertical `\lastskip` over `\write`, or, more generally, is there a way to program a "vertical version" of `\@bsphack` … `\@esphack`?

In the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\author{}
\title{}

\makeatletter
\def\myAux{\write\@auxout{\string\def\string\mypage{\thepage}}}%%does disturb \lastskip
% \def\myAux{}%%                                                 does not disturb \lastskip
\makeatother

\begin{document}

First example: lastskip preserved\par
\vskip5pt

\addvspace{5pt}
Paragraph with 5pt space above: correct\par
\vskip5pt

\myAux
\addvspace{5pt}
Paragraph with 10pt space above: not correct!.
\end{document}
```

my goal is it that the second `\addvspace` behaves just like the first one. How would I need to define the `\myAux`-Macro in order to achieve that?

And, just out of curiosity: why does `\write` reset `\lastskip` to `\z@` in the first place?

Notes:

- According to a comment in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350339/texs-write-command-sometimes-induces-a-spurious-vertical-space), `\immediate\write` would help in this case, however since I want to store the actual page number of the final output, I cannot use `\immediate` (right?).
- assume that the order of text -> space -> write -> space -> text is fixed.  My real-world-example looks like this in the end: [image: subsection followed by a paragraph with two seperate inline headings and a margin note]

  which is a subsection ("3. Keine...") as free-standing heading with
  `0.5\baselineskip` space below, and two consecutive inline-headings (law-makers,
  don't ask…), where the first one has `0.5\baselineskip` space above. If two or more headings clash together, only one of those values should be inserted as vertical skip  (`0.5\baselineskip` instead of `1\baselineskip`).
  In between those two heading blocks there is a macro that produces the number in the
  margin and which also invokes a `\write` to the .aux file:

  ```
  \subsection{3. Keine größeren Wettbewerbsverzerrungen}

  \Randnummer{30}
  \paragraph{a) Allgemeiner Regelungsinhalt.}
  \subparagraph{aa) Noch genauere Beschreibung was der Regelinhalt ist.}

  Selbst wenn...
  ```

  The `\Randnummer`-macro needs to be between the
  `\subsection` and the paragraph headings because the marginnote should be placed at
  the same height as the first line of the inline-headings and not at the height of the `\subsection` nor where the actual text of the paragraph starts,
  therefore I cannot move it behind the `\paragraph`s or before the `\subsection`. I also noted that neither the marginnote-mechanism, nor the
  consecutive headings themselves cause the resetting of `\lastskip`, it is just
  the `\write`.
  The MWE above is the core problem stripped down to the absolute minimum.

Comment: try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651366/2388

Comment: works perfectly, so far. thank you.

Comment: If you look in `ltspace.dtx` just after `\@bsphack` is defined you will find vertical versions commented out with the helpful comment `%    For the moment we are going to ignore the vertical versions until they are correct. \changes{LaTeX2e}{1993/12/19}{There seem to be problems with selfmade birthday presents}`

Comment: hm, so the hyperref macros in Ulrike's answer are basicly what in the latex-kernel is commented out? I don't quite understand whether the additional `\nobreak` in both solutions could potentially do any harm. Does it prevent breaks before or after `\myAux`?

Comment: it prevents adding a break point at the negative skip. Also these days you could/should use `\lastnodetype` to check for an existing skip not `\ifdim \lastskip=\z@` in case there was a zero skip.

Comment: thank you both again for the explanations. Does someone want to compose an up-votable answer?

Comment: or close as dup of Ulrike's answer?

Comment: in the other question's case it was a `\penalty-100` that caused the resetting of `\lastskip`, here it is a `\write`. Or does that not matter because the solution is the same in both cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extra line produced by \Needspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651348/extra-line-produced-by-needspace) (as proposed by David)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner well it is the "right" answer, but in a completely different context... On an abstract level, the problem is the same in both questions (namely that something "destroys" `\lastskip`), but on a user level, they are different: for me it was `\write`, in the other question it was `\penalty`... I'm not sure if it could confuse future users that might have a similar problem as me when this is marked as a "duplicate".

Comment: Ok, I retracted my vote. Maybe you can provide an answer instead (just an idea).